# Trying to understand OpenMP floating numerical errors

Tags: c++, openmp

I recently start to multi-thread (MT) my image processing project using OpenMP.

I didn't had any problem with any functions except with one (not that computation heavy, but more float manipulation compare to int in others).

So first thing, let's say that the single thread (ST) result are equal to the image X, and that the MT results are Y.

When using a small windows to average, X == Y, but when the windows is getting bigger (5x5), X != Y.

So I introduced some "prints" to see values for specific pixels, using print boom! X == Y again. This is what I want to understand. **Why is when I got print in that code, the result are back to result X ?**

Note that I tried to change the float-point model (Intel compiler) to precise and extended and both model gaves that ST and MT were equals, but that new ST result Z != X and much longer then using the default floating-point model.

Edit: The current code :

```
const int tileOffset = 1;

unsigned char** texturePtr = (unsigned char**)texture->getRowPtr();
short** wrkSrcPtr = (short**)wrkSrc->getRowPtr();
short** imFitAPtr = (short**)imFitA->getRowPtr();
short** imFitBPtr = (short**)imFitB->getRowPtr();
short** imFitCPtr = (short**)imFitC->getRowPtr();

// now, compute raw texture value for each pixel using the above plane equations
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(g_options->ompNumberThreads) if(g_options->ompThreaded) 
    {

#pragma omp for  
        for ( int i = 0; i < src->getHeight(); i = i + tileOffset ) {
            for ( int j = 0; j < src->getWidth(); j = j + tileOffset ) {

                bool printPoint = false;                   

                int jVal = 333;
                int iVal = 99;

                if ( j == jVal && i == src->getHeight() - iVal - 1 ) {
                    printPoint = true;
                    printf("\n\nAt (%d, %d) with Thread %d \n", jVal, iVal, omp_get_thread_num());
                }

                jVal = 343;
                iVal = 204;

                if ( j == jVal && i == src->getHeight() - iVal - 1 ) {
                    printPoint = true;
                    printf("\n\nAt (%d, %d) with Thread %d \n", jVal, iVal, omp_get_thread_num());
                }                    

                const int ti = i * tileOffset;
                const int tj = j * tileOffset;

                const float planeA = imFitAPtr[i][j] / 32000.0f*255.0f;
                const float planeB = imFitBPtr[i][j] / 32000.0f*255.0f;
                const float planeC = imFitCPtr[i][j] / 32000.0f*255.0f;

                float sum2 = 0.0f;
                float sum = 0.0f;
                int nbSum = 0;

                if ( printPoint ) {
                    printf("Fit (A,B,C) = (%d, %d, %d) and In float (%f, %f, %f) \n",
                           imFitAPtr[i][j], imFitBPtr[i][j], imFitCPtr[i][j],
                           planeA, planeB, planeC);
                }

                for ( int ri = i - halfROI; ri <= i + halfROI; ri++ ) {
                    for ( int rj = j - halfROI; rj <= j + halfROI; rj++ ) {
                        // sanity checks (image boundaries)
                        if ( ri < 0 || ri >= src->getHeight() || rj < 0 || rj >= src->getWidth() ) continue;

                        // eval the local plane at that pixel and compute the residual
                        const float localPlaneValue = planeA * ( rj - j ) + planeB * ( ri - i ) + planeC;
                        const float residual = wrkSrcPtr[ri][rj] / 32000.0f*255.0f - localPlaneValue;

                        const float rr = residual*residual;

                        if ( printPoint )
                            printf("Local: %f, residual: %f, resSQ: %f, sum2: %f and sum: %f \n ", localPlaneValue, residual, rr, sum2, sum);

                        sum2 += rr;
                        sum += residual;
                        nbSum++;


                        if ( printPoint )
                            printf("Add sum2: %f, add sum: %f and nb: %d \n ", sum2, sum, nbSum);


                    }
                }

                if ( printPoint )
                    printf("\n");

                // the texture for that pixel is the stdev
                float texVal = 0.0f;
                if ( nbSum > 1 ) {
                    texVal = sqrtf(max(( sum2 - sum * sum / nbSum ) / ( nbSum - 1 ), 0.0f)) * scaling;
                    if ( texVal > 255.0f ) texVal = 255;

                }
                texturePtr[ti][tj] = (unsigned char)texVal;

                if ( printPoint )
                    printf("Final value : %d (In float: %f) \n\n", texturePtr[ti][tj], texVal);

            }
        }

    } // End OMP
```

With the "outside print" I noticed that the square residual (rr) and square sum (sum2) were the value that were not stable between ST and MT.

Comment: You probably have a bug in your code (either the parallel version, or even the initial one which only becomes apparent when parallelized). Just post the code and we'll see.

Comment: If the presence/absence of a printing statement affects the result of a computation, there is most likely Undefined Behaviour (a.k.a. a bug) in said computation.

Comment: do you perhaps use `==` to compare floating point numbers?

Comment: @Gilles and Angew,  I edit the post to add the code, I left the print to show where I put them.

Comment: @tobi303 No. The `==` was just an image compare method that do a pixel per pixel comparison (small script on the side).

Comment: I didn't see anything wrong in your code, admitting that all arrays have been properly allocated contiguously with the same height and width. Is that the case? And did you also check their types?

Comment: All the arrays are good. I already check those before. The plane variable A,B,C are equal in between ST and MT. Those are all short arrays and yes contiguously. And the source image (unsigned char) has been convert to Short also and this look good. I don't understand what can be wrong. I check and recheck the image before and I could not understand what was wrong there.

Comment: So that might be that your algorithm is numerically unstable and that while enabling the OpenMP and/or adding the print statements, you changed the way the compiler did the numerical optimizations. The main point where the changes might happen is that by forcing the storing of the intermediary data instead of keeping it in registers. The actual precision in registers might be larger than the one defined in the code (40b vs. 32b), which for an unstable algorithm, might lead to numerical discrepancies.

Comment: Hmm. I understand part of what you said. I might need to check about that register precision thing. But I also think it's numerically unstable, specially when I change the floating-point model of the compiler to precise, the algorithm was giving similar result between ST and MT. But now, I need to check what I can do to ensure similar result, I want to avoid difference between my original code and the OpenMP one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to the compiler under windows.

This code is compiled with Intel Composer XE 2015. But when I tried to use Visual Studio v140, it's seems the code is similar with and without OMP.

I didn't tried with a newer Intel Compiler (such as 2017). And this problem doesn't occur on Intel Composer XE 2015 under Linux.